# Extracting country name from dataframe column- Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, extract, country

I am trying to extract the country name from one of the data frame columns. The data frame looks like below image link:
[Data Frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiHwx.png)
Data frame: 
Department of Atmospheric Science, Yunnan University, Kunming, China
I have something similar to the above text in each row of the affiliation column.

I want to extract country names from the Affiliation column and keep them in a new column for each row.
I am new to Python and have tried below code, but it didn't work and returned nothing.

```
Cntr = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in authors.Affiliation:
        Cntr.append(country.name)
```

Comment: You could just take the last dataframe columns `df['Affiliation']` and apply a function which strips of all characters after the last comma

Comment: @UmarAftab: the final element has two countries in it.

Comment: @mechanical_meat that is why I up voted you !

Answer (score 1):

try using split function:

```
df['new_column_name']=df['Affiliation'].to_string().split(',')[-1]
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: The only problem with this is that in the final element there are two countries: United Kingdom and China.

Comment: oh I see, let me figure out it again, so for the final element, the corresponding value should contain two values???bcz there are two countries..

Comment: Right, this is my understanding. Because there are two boxes around the two countries.

Comment: right, if this is the scenario, then agreed with your answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this condition it may work.

```
if len([x for x in authors.Affiliation if re.search(subs, x)]) > 0:
    Cntr.append(country.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pycountry.countries` is not returning a list of countries. First, you need to extract country names.

```
name = []
for i in list(pycountry.countries):
    name.append(i.name)
Cntr = []
for country in name:
    if country.name in authors.Affiliation:
        Cntr.append(country.name)
```

Comment: It's iterable: https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry/blob/master/src/pycountry/db.py#L97

Comment: The point is that I need a country for each author, also I have some null affiliation, I need a column of the country in a data frame because I should assign a country to each row based on the authors ID.

Comment: @Hamid Thanks! Your code worked well and I could get the list of countries, is that any way to get both country and author ID for each row?